# How can I force a list item to display on one line with CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm using list items as "fake menu items" like so:

```
 <li>Match
    <ul class="second-level-menu">
      <li class="inlineblock" id="mniMatchWorkersWithJobLocs" name="mniMatchWorkersWithJobLocs">Workers with Jobs/Locations</li>
      <li id="mniMatchWorkersWithShifts" name="mniMatchWorkersWithShifts">Workers with Shifts</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

The problem is that the longer sub-menu items, such as "Workers with Jobs/Locations" are breaking over two lines; I want them to stay on one line.

I pseudo-cleverly thought it would be enough to simply assign the li this class:

```
.inlineblock {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

...but it doesn't cut the mustard. What am I missing or misthinking?

### UPDATE

Based on the answers, I now have this CSS:

```
.inlineblock {
  display: inline-block;
}
li.inlineblock ul li{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

...and this HTML:

```
  <li class="inlineblock">Match
    <ul class="second-level-menu">
      <li id="mniMatchWorkersWithJobLocs" name="mniMatchWorkersWithJobLocs">Workers with Jobs/Locations</li>
      <li id="mniMatchWorkersWithShifts" name="mniMatchWorkersWithShifts">Workers with Shifts</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

...but I still see this:

[image]

Here is the entire HTML for the fake menus:

```
<template name="mnuScheduler">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="col-All">
      <nav>
        <ul class="top-level-menu">
          <li>Schedules
            <ul class="second-level-menu">
              <li id="mniOpenExisting" name="mniOpenExisting">Open Existing</li>
              <li>Create New...
                <ul class="third-level-menu">
                  <li id="mniCreateNewScheduleBasedOnExisting" name="mniCreateNewScheduleBasedOnExisting">Based on Existing</li>
                  <li id="mniCreateNewScheduleFromScratch" name="mniCreateNewScheduleFromScratch">From Scratch</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li id="mniSaveCurrentSchedule" name="mniSaveCurrentSchedule">Save Current</li>
              <li id="mniEmailCurrentSchedule" name="mniEmailCurrentSchedule">Email Current</li>
              <li id="mniPrintCurrentSchedule" name="mniPrintCurrentSchedule">Print Current</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Jobs/Locations
            <ul class="second-level-menu">
              <li id="mniAddNewJobLoc" name="mniAddNewJobLoc">Add New</li>
              <li id="mniViewOrEditJobLoc" name="mniViewOrEditJobLoc">View or Edit</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Shifts
            <ul class="second-level-menu">
              <li id="mniAddNewShift" name="mniAddNewShift">Add New</li>
              <li id="mniViewOrEditShift" name="mniViewOrEditShift">View or Edit</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Workers
            <ul class="second-level-menu">
              <li id="mniAddNewWorker" name="mniAddNewWorker">Add New</li>
              <li id="mniViewOrEditWorker" name="mniViewOrEditWorker">View or Edit</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="inlineblock">Match
            <ul class="second-level-menu">
              <li id="mniMatchWorkersWithJobLocs" name="mniMatchWorkersWithJobLocs">Workers with Jobs/Locations</li>
              <li id="mniMatchWorkersWithShifts" name="mniMatchWorkersWithShifts">Workers with Shifts</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Rules
            <ul class="second-level-menu">
              <li id="mniSetRules" name="mniSetRules">Establish/Maintain</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Help
            <ul class="second-level-menu">
              <li id="mniAbout" name="mniAbout">About</li>
              <li id="mniHowTo" name="mniHowTo">How To...</li>
              <li id="mniContact" name="mniContact">Contact Us</li>
              <li id="mniAcquireLicense" name="mniAcquireLicense">Acquire License</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

### UPDATE 2

This:

```
CSS:
.inlineblock {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
li.inlineblock ul li{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

```
  <li class="inlineblock">Match
    <ul class="second-level-menu">
      <li id="mniMatchWorkersWithJobLocs" name="mniMatchWorkersWithJobLocs">Workers with Jobs/Locations</li>
      <li id="mniMatchWorkersWithShifts" name="mniMatchWorkersWithShifts">Workers with Shifts</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

...caused both submenu items to appear on the same line (one step forward, two steps back)

This:

```
/*.inlineblock {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
li.inlineblock ul li{
  display: inline-block;
}*/
li {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

...does put the two menu items on their own separate line, but the first one is "cut off" (it reads "Workers with Jobs/Lo")

### UPDATE 3

In response to Joseph Marikle's request, here is all the CSS:

```
html {
  font-family:'Segoe UI Light', 'Bookman Old Style', Calibri, Candara, serif;
}
header {
  background: #d2edf4;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d0edf5, #e1e5f0 100%);
  padding: 20px 15px 15px 15px;
  position: relative;
}
/*body {
  font-family: 'Palatino Linotype', 'Bookman Antigua', Palatino, serif;
  background-color: lightyellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;

  font-size: 14px;

  width:80%;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  padding: 10px 50px 200px;
}*/
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 50px 48px 0;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #333;
  background: #FFF;
  font-family: ff-tis-web-pro, 'Palatino Linotype', 'Bookman Antigua', Palatino, Georgia, serif;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
nav {
    background-color: forestgreen;
}
form {
    background-color: lightyellow;
}
h1 {
  color: navy;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", serif;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
h2 {
  font-family: 'Bookman Old Style', Verdana, sans-serif;
}
input:focus {
  background-color: lightyellow;
}
input:hover {
  background-color: azure;
}
table {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: azure;
  /*min-height: 100%;*/
  margin-top: 80px;
}
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid navy;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    /*text-align: left;*/
}
input[type="text"] {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
input[type="submit"] {
  margin-top: 8px;
}
input[type="time"] {
  margin: 3px;
}
p {
  font-size: 14px;
}

[class*='col-'] {
    float: left;
    margin: 4px;
}
.grid {
  background: white;
}
.module {
  background: lightyellow;
}
.col-All {
    width: 90%;
}
.col-2-3 {
    width: 60%;
}
.col-1-3 {
    width: 30%;
}
.col-1-2 {
    width: 45%;
}
.col-1-4 {
    width: 22.5%;
}

/* for aligning input texts that follow labels on forms and such; can create other sizes too (label120,etc.) */
.label88 {
    width: 88px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.label144 {
    width: 144px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.joblocoptionallabel {
  width: 124px;
  display: inline-block;
}
/*.inlineblock {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
li.inlineblock ul li{
  display: inline-block;
}*/
li {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
}
.smallcaps {
    font-variant: small-caps;
}
.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: lightyellow;
}
.dateLabel {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Candara, 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
  color: forestgreen;
}
.shiftLabel {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: Calibri, serif;
  color: red;
}
.jobLoc {
  margin-right: 16px;
  width: 115px;
}
.jobLocCount {
  width: 40px;
}
.trabajar {
  width: 159px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  margin-top: 4px;
}
.shortTextInput {
    width: 64px;
}
.floatleft {
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
/* Menu-specific styles/rules, adapted from  */
.third-level-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -150px;
    width: 150px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
}
.third-level-menu > li {
    height: 30px;
    background: gray;
}
.third-level-menu > li:hover {
    background: white;
}
.second-level-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
}
.second-level-menu > li {
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
    background: orange;
    color: white;
}
.second-level-menu > li:hover {
    background: green;
}
.top-level-menu {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
    /*border: 1px; <= not working*/
}
.top-level-menu > li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    background: moccasin;
}
.top-level-menu > li:hover {
    background: lightgray;
}
.top-level-menu li:hover > ul {
    /* On hover, display the next level's menu */
    display: inline;
}
/* End of Menu-specific Styles */
```

Comment: did you try `white-space:nowrap;`?

Comment: @JosephMarikle what did ' white-space:nowrap; ' do? I tried it and nothing happened

Comment: Oops.  Sotty, @L-X.  Didn't see your comment. It forces no wrapping on whitespace.  B. Clay, Please post your CSS too.  It looks like your CSS uses absolutely positioned elements with `width:100%`.  It might be possible to fix the items getting cut off by changing that to `min-width: 100%`, but it's hard to tell without the original CSS.

Comment: @JosephMarikle: Update3 has all the CSS

Comment: Yeah, changing `width:150px;` to `min-width:100%;` on `.second-level-menu` might help: http://jsfiddle.net/jL7cyjm8/

Comment: @JosephMarikle: I'll try it tonight; thanks.

Comment: @JosephMarikle: Make that an answer, and I'll mark it as such.

Comment: Sorry about all the comments.  I just wasn't sure my suggestions were viable solutions, so I was trying to find out more information.  I've posted an answer per your request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initial issue was that the list items were wrapping around in a menu that should ideally keep the full name on a single line.  The first proposed solution is to apply `white-space:nowrap`, but in this particular instance, the original poster had a menu that would cut off overflow (using `overflow:hidden`).  To overcome this, it was much simpler to just change the width of the embed container list (a simple `ul` element).  A width of `150px` was originally set presumably to ensure that the menu looks uniform for submenu items with items that have short names.  This same effect can be achieved without losing the wide of extra wide lists by setting (or leaving) the width at `auto` and giving it a `min-width: 100%;`.  This works because the submenus are relative to the parent li items.  100% will be the same width as the parent `li`.

**TL;DR**: In summary, removing the width and adding a min-width of 100% solved the issue for the OP.

Code with the changes below:

```css
html {
  font-family:'Segoe UI Light', 'Bookman Old Style', Calibri, Candara, serif;
}
header {
  background: #d2edf4;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d0edf5, #e1e5f0 100%);
  padding: 20px 15px 15px 15px;
  position: relative;
}
/*body {
  font-family: 'Palatino Linotype', 'Bookman Antigua', Palatino, serif;
  background-color: lightyellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;

  font-size: 14px;

  width:80%;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  padding: 10px 50px 200px;
}*/
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 50px 48px 0;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #333;
  background: #FFF;
  font-family: ff-tis-web-pro, 'Palatino Linotype', 'Bookman Antigua', Palatino, Georgia, serif;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
nav {
    background-color: forestgreen;
}
form {
    background-color: lightyellow;
}
h1 {
  color: navy;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", serif;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
h2 {
  font-family: 'Bookman Old Style', Verdana, sans-serif;
}
input:focus {
  background-color: lightyellow;
}
input:hover {
  background-color: azure;
}
table {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: azure;
  /*min-height: 100%;*/
  margin-top: 80px;
}
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid navy;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    /*text-align: left;*/
}
input[type="text"] {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
input[type="submit"] {
  margin-top: 8px;
}
input[type="time"] {
  margin: 3px;
}
p {
  font-size: 14px;
}

[class*='col-'] {
    float: left;
    margin: 4px;
}
.grid {
  background: white;
}
.module {
  background: lightyellow;
}
.col-All {
    width: 90%;
}
.col-2-3 {
    width: 60%;
}
.col-1-3 {
    width: 30%;
}
.col-1-2 {
    width: 45%;
}
.col-1-4 {
    width: 22.5%;
}

/* for aligning input texts that follow labels on forms and such; can create other sizes too (label120,etc.) */
.label88 {
    width: 88px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.label144 {
    width: 144px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.joblocoptionallabel {
  width: 124px;
  display: inline-block;
}
/*.inlineblock {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
li.inlineblock ul li{
  display: inline-block;
}*/
li {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
}
.smallcaps {
    font-variant: small-caps;
}
.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: lightyellow;
}
.dateLabel {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Candara, 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
  color: forestgreen;
}
.shiftLabel {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: Calibri, serif;
  color: red;
}
.jobLoc {
  margin-right: 16px;
  width: 115px;
}
.jobLocCount {
  width: 40px;
}
.trabajar {
  width: 159px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  margin-top: 4px;
}
.shortTextInput {
    width: 64px;
}
.floatleft {
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
/* Menu-specific styles/rules, adapted from  */
.third-level-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -150px;
    width: 150px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
}
.third-level-menu > li {
    height: 30px;
    background: gray;
}
.third-level-menu > li:hover {
    background: white;
}
.second-level-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    /*width: 150px;*/
    min-width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
}
.second-level-menu > li {
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
    background: orange;
    color: white;
}
.second-level-menu > li:hover {
    background: green;
}
.top-level-menu {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
    /*border: 1px; <= not working*/
}
.top-level-menu > li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    background: moccasin;
}
.top-level-menu > li:hover {
    background: lightgray;
}
.top-level-menu li:hover > ul {
    /* On hover, display the next level's menu */
    display: inline;
}
/* End of Menu-specific Styles */
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="col-All">
      <nav>
        <ul class="top-level-menu">
          <li>Schedules
            <ul class="second-level-menu">
              <li id="mniOpenExisting" name="mniOpenExisting">Open Existing</li>
              <li>Create New...
                <ul class="third-level-menu">
                  <li id="mniCreateNewScheduleBasedOnExisting" name="mniCreateNewScheduleBasedOnExisting">Based on Existing</li>
                  <li id="mniCreateNewScheduleFromScratch" name="mniCreateNewScheduleFromScratch">From Scratch</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li id="mniSaveCurrentSchedule" name="mniSaveCurrentSchedule">Save Current</li>
              <li id="mniEmailCurrentSchedule" name="mniEmailCurrentSchedule">Email Current</li>
              <li id="mniPrintCurrentSchedule" name="mniPrintCurrentSchedule">Print Current</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Jobs/Locations
            <ul class="second-level-menu">
              <li id="mniAddNewJobLoc" name="mniAddNewJobLoc">Add New</li>
              <li id="mniViewOrEditJobLoc" name="mniViewOrEditJobLoc">View or Edit</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Shifts
            <ul class="second-level-menu">
              <li id="mniAddNewShift" name="mniAddNewShift">Add New</li>
              <li id="mniViewOrEditShift" name="mniViewOrEditShift">View or Edit</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Workers
            <ul class="second-level-menu">
              <li id="mniAddNewWorker" name="mniAddNewWorker">Add New</li>
              <li id="mniViewOrEditWorker" name="mniViewOrEditWorker">View or Edit</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="inlineblock">Match
            <ul class="second-level-menu">
              <li id="mniMatchWorkersWithJobLocs" name="mniMatchWorkersWithJobLocs">Workers with Jobs/Locations</li>
              <li id="mniMatchWorkersWithShifts" name="mniMatchWorkersWithShifts">Workers with Shifts</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Rules
            <ul class="second-level-menu">
              <li id="mniSetRules" name="mniSetRules">Establish/Maintain</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Help
            <ul class="second-level-menu">
              <li id="mniAbout" name="mniAbout">About</li>
              <li id="mniHowTo" name="mniHowTo">How To...</li>
              <li id="mniContact" name="mniContact">Contact Us</li>
              <li id="mniAcquireLicense" name="mniAcquireLicense">Acquire License</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you just need to give them both the class,

```
 <li>Match
    <ul class="second-level-menu">
      <li class="inlineblock" id="mniMatchWorkersWithJobLocs" name="mniMatchWorkersWithJobLocs">Workers with Jobs/Locations</li>
      <li class="inlineblock" id="mniMatchWorkersWithShifts" name="mniMatchWorkersWithShifts">Workers with Shifts</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

This way stops you needing to always add the class and will convert all li's in the list to inline.

HTML

```
<li class="inlineblock">Match
    <ul class="second-level-menu">
      <li id="mniMatchWorkersWithJobLocs" name="mniMatchWorkersWithJobLocs">Workers with Jobs/Locations</li>
      <li id="mniMatchWorkersWithShifts" name="mniMatchWorkersWithShifts">Workers with Shifts</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

CSS

```
li.inlineblock ul li{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[Code Example](http://jsfiddle.net/31s14whk/1/)

If you want Matdch to be on the same line then.

CSS

```
li.inlineblock,li.inlineblock ul,li.inlineblock ul li{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[Code Example](http://jsfiddle.net/31s14whk/2/)

Comment: I just noticed you answered the same thing

Answer (score 1):

I suggest put your text elements inside of a block element such as anchor,paragraph,label etc... tags, otherwise you can use the css for non-breaking lines:

```
li
{
   white-space:nowrap
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use 'white-space: nowrap;' in your Css.

```
.inlineblock {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

I would suggest not getting into a habit of using class names like that here in the future bc it could lead to confusion. Names like "foo" and "bar" always work.

Answer (score 1):

You should be applying the class to the list itself, rather than each list item.

**HTML:**

```
<li class="inlineblock">Match
    <ul class="second-level-menu">
      <li id="mniMatchWorkersWithJobLocs" name="mniMatchWorkersWithJobLocs">Workers with Jobs/Locations</li>
      <li id="mniMatchWorkersWithShifts" name="mniMatchWorkersWithShifts">Workers with Shifts</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

This will ensure that all items are displayed in block.

**CSS:**

```
li.inlineblock ul li{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

That will set the list items of the unordered list within the Match list to display in-line like you would like to see.